# error usando multer con node.js

Tags: nodejs, backend, multer

Hola estoy tratando de crear una funcionalidad en mi aplicacion de cargar imagenes usando multer pero cuando hago la peticion a traves de Postman me sale el error 404. He revisado todo el codigo pero no encuentro el error...

Este es el codigo en la carpeta controllers dentro de un fichero llamado upload :

```
const multer = require('multer')

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '/public/images')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, `${Date.now()}-${file.originalname}`)
    }
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

exports.upload = upload.single('myFile')

exports.uploadFile = (req, res) => {
    res.send({ data: 'Enviar un archivo' })
}
```

Este es el codigo de la ruta upload:

```
const express = require('express')

const controller = require('../controllers/upload')

const router = express.Router()


/**
 * Ruta: /user GET
 */
router.post(
    '/upload',
    controller.upload,
    controller.uploadFile
)


module.exports = router
```

En el fichero principal de la aplicacion app.js este es el codig completo:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
const passport = require('passport')
const session = require('express-session')
const flash = require('connect-flash')
const multer = require('multer')

// connection to the DB
require('./lib/connectMongoose');

// require passport
require('./passport/local-auth')

// connection to API
const usersApi = require('./routes/api/users')
const postsRouter = require('./routes/api/posts')
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'mysecretsession',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(passport.authenticate('session'));

app.use(flash())
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.use((req, res, next)=> {
  app.locals.registerMessage = req.flash('registerMessage')
  app.locals.loginMessage = req.flash('loginMessage')
  next();
});

// API routes
app.use('/api/posts', postsRouter);

app.use('/api/users', usersApi);
app.use('/api/', require ('./routes/api/login'));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Las imagenes deberian guardarse dentro de una carpeta llamada public dentro de otra subcarpeta llamada images... La llamada al servidor es con localhost:3000/upload

Answer (score 0):

El problema parece residir en la ruta en la que estas guardando las imágenes, estas deben guardarse en /public/images verdad? entonces prueba el siguiente código:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'images'))
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, `${Date.now()}-${file.originalname}`)
    }
})
```

Para eso debes importar o requerir el modulo 'path' que tiene utilidades para las rutas de archivos, recuerda hacer el require/import de ese modulo

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso, había actualizado mi dependencia a 2.0.0-rs.4, y siempre me genero errores, volvía a la versión inicial de "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1" y funciono en todas las versiones mas recientes de NodeJS estoy actualmente en la v20.0.3

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).